# Who is Sera talking to?

Tags: plot-explanation, leaving-las-vegas

In [*Leaving Las Vegas*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113627/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt), Sera is seen talking to the camera or an unseen person as if she is being interviewed.  There are clips throughout the movie of her doing this.  The conversations begin with her talking about her profession of being a prostitute and slowly move to her talking about Ben and their relationship together as the movie progresses.

One such scene shows Sera talking to the camera (or unseen person) about her relationship with Ben:

> I think we realized that we   didn't have long and accepted   it. My
>   charm, for him, was   that I accepted him exactly     as he was and didn't
>   expect    him to change. I think we   both realized that about each
>     other. Ben needed me and I  liked his drama. I loved him.

**Is it ever explained who she is talking to while she is revealing these stories?**

Comment: Wikipedia indicates a *therapist*.

Comment: @Paulie_D Hmmmm...yeah, I saw that.  I also saw on other sites that she was making some sort of biography of her life and others that say she was talking to "unnamed person" (including the script). So, I don't really know.  I guess the most reliable source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

She's talking to a therapist. Figgis used this to allow her character to convey her thoughts, as he explains in [Bette Gordon's interview](https://bombmagazine.org/articles/mike-figgis/) for *Bomb*:

> **Bette Gordon:** The love interest, Sera—were her psychotherapy scenes in the book?
>
> **Mike Figgis:** The principle difficulty in making a book like *Leaving Las
>   Vegas*—which I think is a brilliant book—into a film is that it is
>   existential. A lot of it is in his head, stream of consciousness
>   stuff. You really have to study it to work out, Is this past tense? Is
>   this a fantasy? Is this happening now? It really doesn’t help much
>   when you come to translating it into sequential film narrative—which
>   is a bit stupid compared to the freedom of a novel. She had all the
>   stream of consciousness stuff as well, O’Brien wrote it from Sera’s
>   and Ben’s points of view …
>
> **Bette Gordon:** Ah, interesting, so it oscillates between the two points of views.
>
> **Mike Figgis:** You’re in both of their heads. The device of him being a drunk
>   gives him artistic license to tell his back story poetically, or talk
>   to other people, ’cause he’s a drunk he can say whatever he wants. She
>   doesn’t have that voice, and yet she has internal thoughts. **I had
>   wrestled with three drafts, got it pared down to the bone stuff, and
>   was about to go into production, but I had this nagging fear that she
>   didn’t have enough of a voice away from talking to him. In order for a
>   love story to be two-handed, she needed this voice.** So I went back to
>   all the outtakes in the novel of her stream of consciousness stuff.
>   **The therapy was the only way I could think of to include it other than
>   voice-over, which I don’t like.**

To Figgis these scenes can be explained easily:

> **The idea of her talking, as it
>   happens, to her shrink, makes sense because it’s an American film. And
>   I like the idea that a prostitute would go to a shrink anyway.** When
>   you work through the logic, if you’re earning five, six, seven
>   thousand a week, you buy a lot of quick things. You probably go to a
>   gym, and why not go to a shrink? You’ve got a lot to get rid of. It is
>   a way of keeping yourself together if you aren’t religious.

The circumstances surrounding the filming of these scenes are notable as well:

> **So I shot
>   her therapy scenes as a camera test before we even started shooting
>   the film. Elisabeth and I, the camera man and sound man set up—she
>   changed her clothes every twenty minutes, and it took us about two
>   hours. I asked her questions off-camera, and didn’t overlap her
>   dialogue, just played the shrink, which was not that difficult.**
>
> When
>   we got to the end of the actual shoot I thought, I’d better look at
>   that footage again, because I suspect it’s going to end up in the
>   film. She hadn’t even shot her first scene with Nic yet when we did
>   it. She knew intellectually how tragic the story is, but she hadn’t
>   gotten into it. And I thought we might have to spend another two hours
>   one evening shooting more stuff. So I went back to the editing table
>   and put it up, and I was just blown away with how fluently on the
>   button she was, pre-having met Ben, and saying, “I don’t know if I
>   should see him again but I looked for him on the street last night.”
>   That was completely from Elisabeth. I said to her, “Are you going to
>   see him again?” She got that catch in her voice and said, “I found
>   myself looking for him on the street last night.” I was in tears and I
>   thought, she doesn’t have to reshoot anything. **So that was all a
>   camera test. Everything. Including the section after his death.**

The interviewer points out that the "therapist" device has been used before in movies by referring to a famous example:

> **Bette Gordon:** Remember *Klute*?
>
> **Mike Figgis:** I do. Great footage. Having made that decision there was a little
>   nag and I thought—I’ve seen this before somewhere. And *Elate* is one of
>   my favorite films. But I hadn’t seen it for a long time. I do remember
>   that she goes to the shrink and I purposely didn’t go and check it out
>   again.

---

[Figgis' annotated book version of his screenplay](https://books.google.be/books?id=eANL4yGgcckC) offers some more information:

> In pre-production I took a tough look at the script. This is always a
>   crucial moment on a film because the actors are in  place and
>   practical decisions are being made about locations and so on. The
>   story starts to be real. **I liked the script but I  had a nagging worry
>   that Sera didn't have enough of a voice in the story.** In the book
>   there is a lot of internal thought from her, but in the script it was
>   difficult to find a way of expressing those ideas. Her thoughts are
>   about her job as well as  about Ben and they are not the kind of ideas
>   that could be expressed in the context of dialogue to him. Ben, on the
>   other  hand, is a drunk and has licence to be as expressive as he
>   likes. For example, his thoughts in the bank are recorded on a 
>   portable tape machine and we learn something about him. Sera's
>   character does not have that freedom. **So I came up  with with idea of
>   her talking to a therapist (not a new device, I remember it in *Klute*).**
>   I went back to the book and found all  the interesting stuff about her
>   and put it into the script as therapy sessions. I reasoned that she
>   would have plenty of cash  and if everyone else in the US is talking
>   to a shrink, why wouldn't a prostitute?

However, not everyone agreed with this approach:

> Lila Cazes (the Producer from Lumiere  pictures) didn't like these
>   changes at all and asked me to take them out of the script again,
>   which I did.

But Figgis persevered anyway:

> However, I was  still concerned about the imbalance, so I did a sneaky
>   thing. We shot a camera test the week before the shoot and I  asked
>   Elisabeth to wear her costume. **I gave her all the deleted text to read
>   and then, on camera, I interviewed her in her  character as Sera and
>   she improvised her answers based on the material from the book.** Some
>   other things came out of  the sessions which had a lot more emotion in
>   them, and I think these elements were crucial to her character. She
>   told me  afterwards that it was a great way of getting into character.
>
> [...]
>
> The Lumiere folk were not happy that I'd done this, but I told them
>   that it  had cost them nothing and we should think of it as insurance
>   and probably wouldn't use it. They calmed down, but in my  heart I
>   knew it would end up in the film.

Figgis planned on reshooting these scenes:

> Towards the end of the shoot I remembered the footage and thought I
>   should take another look at it because, after all,  on the day we did
>   it Lisa hadn't even done a scene with Nic and hadn't really formed her
>   character. I had in mind the idea  of stealing an hour one night to do
>   some more therapy. I asked Waldemar Kalinowsky (Production Designer)
>   to get the  couch ready. I viewed the footage again and was blown away
>   by how accurate her emotions were. I was moved to tears  by the last
>   scene and cancelled the extra 'illegal' shoot.

Notably, the first cut of the movie lacked the therapy scenes:

> None of these therapy scenes appeared in the first cut of the film.
>   This was deliberate. I wanted to be absolutely sure  that they were
>   needed. Afterwards we quickly made a second pass and added everything.

Answer (score 1):

Sera went to see a therapist after Ben passed away. Except for the opening scene which depicts Bens final days in Los Angeles before making the decision to move, the story is explained to us through a visit between Sera and her therapist. Being all alone, one can only assume Sera needed someone to talk to after Bens passing. She was in love with him. So much, that she accepted him and his decision unconditionally. Her final statement to the therapists being, "... I accepted him completely.."

Comment: Where is this explained in the film?